# Действие при закрытии формы

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.x, форма

Вопрос состоит в том, как при нажатии кнопки закрытия формы не закрывать ее, а выполнять функцую, которую я пропишу.

Comment: А когда это окна стали закрываться сами по себе? У кнопки есть параметр command. Ему присваиваете нужную вам функцию.

Comment: У меня задание такое: при нажатии на закрытие форма должна сдвинутся вниз на 20px. Как вообще двигать ее, я знаю, а как назначить какое-либо действие при нажатии кнопки Закрыть, не пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handler)

def handler():
    # Тут ваши действия
    #root.quit() # Не забываем выйти
    # UPD. Советуют так:
    root.destroy()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295270/overriding-tkinter-x-button-control-the-button-that-close-the-window

Comment: Если несложно, можно ваш  майл, контакт, скайп для непостоянных вопросов.